# how run RadPivotGrid1_NeedDataSource method from button

Tags: c#, asp.net

how run RadPivotGrid1_NeedDataSource method from button1 :

```
    protected void RadPivotGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, PivotGridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        string q = @"
                  select * from zomorod_webapp_temp.dbo.ActivationDaily_Report
                  ";
        myReader r = new myReader();
        DataTable dt = r.myQuery(q);
       (sender as RadPivotGrid).DataSource = dt;
    }   
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ???
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I think this should work</strike>

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     RadPivotGrid1_NeedDataSource(sender, null);
 }
```

I have not tried this.

Or simply do this

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       string q = @"select * from zomorod_webapp_temp.dbo.ActivationDaily_Report";
       myReader r = new myReader();
       DataTable dt = r.myQuery(q);
       RadPivotGrid.DataSource = dt;
 }
```

Or even better

```
 protected void BindData()
 {
       string q = @"select * from zomorod_webapp_temp.dbo.ActivationDaily_Report";
       myReader r = new myReader();
       DataTable dt = r.myQuery(q);
       RadPivotGrid.DataSource = dt;
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      BindData();
 }

 protected void RadPivotGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, PivotGridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
 {
      BindData();
 }
```

Comment: its not worked :     Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Yes you are write. Why don't you use the second option. Simply bind the source in the method itself.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: ya second snippet should work here        https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/server-side-binding/advanced-data-binding-(using-needdatasource-event)

Comment: i change RadPivotGrid.DataSource = dt; to RadPivotGrid1.DataSource = dt;  its worked thanks

Comment: @Hisen kindly mark the question as selected answer if it helped.